# Як правильно вживати прикметник "симпатичний"?

Tags: прикметники

Чи правильно вживати "симпатичний" до ґаджетів, їжі, будинку, дерева, машини?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [**СИМПАТИЧНИЙ**](http://sum.in.ua/s/sympatychnyj), а, е.
> ...
> 2. *розм.* Приємний, милий, привабливий. *Багаті акорди, симпатичні арії розворушили її артистичну вдачу* (Нечуй-Левицький, III, 1956, 228); *Сходами підіймається Макс. Це квітучий, добре збудований юнак з.. розумним, симпатичним обличчям* (Іван Кочерга, II, 1956, 267); — *Особливо симпатичні взаємини встановились у мене з простим народом* (Дмитро Бедзик, Дніпро.., 1951, 11).

Якщо арія, обличчя чи взаємини можуть бути симпатичними, то гадаю, що й ґаджети та їжа також.

Answer (score 2):

У результатах пошуку [«симпатичний + <неістота>»](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/freqml?corpname=grac10&q=aword%2C%5Blemma%3D%22%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D+%5Btag%3D%22noun.*inanim.*%22%5D&freqlevel=1&ml1attr=lemma&ml1ctx=0%7E0%3E0) в «Генеральному регіонально анотованому корпусі української мови» версії 10 я знайшов зокрема такі приклади:

- [симпатичний будин(оч)ок/будівля/дім/домівка/квартира/котедж/маєток/міст(ечк)о/особняк/помешкання/споруда/установа/хат(ин)(к)а](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD(%D0%BE%D1%87)?%D0%BE%D0%BA%7C%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%7C%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BC%7C%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%7C%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%7C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B6%7C%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%94%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%7C%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82(%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA)?%D0%BE%7C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BA%7C%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%7C%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%7C%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%7C%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82(%D0%B8%D0%BD)?%D0%BA?%D0%B0%22%5D) — 60, наприклад:

  > Мажорне сонце грає зайчиками у вікнах симпатичних будинків і своїми ласкавими біло-рожевими проміннями благословляє його важку путь (Микола Хвильовий, «Іван Іванович», 1929);
- [симпатичне ім'я/місце/річ/факт/штука/явище](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D1%96%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%7C%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%7C%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%7C%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%7C%D1%88%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%7C%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%22+%26+word=%22%5B%5E%D0%90-%D0%AF%5D.*%22%5D) — 21, наприклад:

  > Чималу надію на добрий розвиток туркменських студій навіває нам той симпатичний факт, що в Ашхабаді заснувавсь Інститут туркменської культури і що взагалі тепер там пожвавішало наукове життя, яке виявляє себе і опублікуванням народнотуркменських текстів (Агатангел Кримський, «Тюрки, їх мови та літератури», 1930);
- [симпатична блискавка/капелюшок/костюмчик/кофтинка/плаття/сукенка/сукня](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%7C%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA%7C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8E%D0%BC%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%7C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%7C%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F%7C%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%7C%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%8F%22%5D) — 17;
- [симпатична іграшка/лялька/сувенір(чик)](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%7C%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0%7C%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%80(%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)?%22%5D) — 13;
- [симпатична гора/озерце/річечка/рослинка](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%7C%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B5%7C%D1%80%D1%96%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%7C%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%22%5D) — 13;
- [симпатична кав'ярня/ресторан(чик)/шин(оч)ок](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F%7C%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD(%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)?%7C%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD(%D0%BE%D1%87)?%D0%BE%D0%BA%22%5D) — 12;
- [симпатична книжечка/томик](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%7C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%22%5D) — 7;
- [симпатичний пам'ятник/скульптура](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac10&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=%5Blemma=%22%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%22%5D+%5Blemma=%22%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%7C%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BF%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%22%5D) — 6.

Тобто принаймні практично подібні словосполучення вживаються, зокрема такими відомими авторами як Микола Хвильовий (*симпатичний будинок*), Валер'ян Підмогильний (*симпатична страва*) тощо.